# Error when deleting an object with a pointer

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I was curious how to delete an object, but got some problems on the way there.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test{
  int x;
public:
    void izpis(){ cout << x; }
    test(){ x = 1; }
    ~test(){ cout << "brisem"; }
};

int main()
{
    test a;
    test *pa = &a;
    pa->izpis();
    delete pa;
}
```

Then I get this error: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

Comment: You didn't `new` this object, so why do you `delete` it?

Comment: You can only `delete` what you have created with `new`. Why do you think you need `delete` here? `new` and `delete` shouldn't be taught at the beginning, so you should know that you don't need it with "normal" variable declarations such as `test a;`.

Comment: yes, after I put `test *pa =  new test;`, it works.

Comment: @TimHajdinjak You shouldn't use `delete` nor `new` here.

Answer (score 0):

Calls to new and delete must match, calls to new[] and delete[] must match and calls for malloc and free must match. If they are not exactly paired bad things happen.

In your case you are trying to freeing memory in the middle of the stack.